# C++ Beginner Lambda's

Tags: c++, function, lambda, scope

I'm a beginner that's just learning about lambdas and so I just want to make a lambda that captures a local variable from the outside function and is supposed to print its value and decrement it until it reaches 0. It  compiles but doesn't display anything. Why?

```
void dummyFn(int &num)
{
    int j = num;                                  
    [&j](){
        while (j != 0)
        {
            cout << j << endl;
            --j;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Why are you quoting yourself?!

Answer (score 4):

You have defined a lambda, but you never run it. Try

```
auto mylambda = [&j](){...}; 
mylambda();
```

Answer (score 2):

*"It compiles but doesn't display anything."*

You need to call it using `()`

```
void dummyFn(int& num)
{
    int j = num;                                  
    [&j](){
        while (j != 0)
        {
            cout << j << endl;
            --j;
        }
    } (); // Call the function !
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda is defined, but now you have to run it:

```
auto fn = [&j](){ ... };  // definition
fn();                     // Run
```

Or even:

```
[&j](){ ... } ();
//            ^^^
```

Both examples are running the function.